# Intel 8086 Assembly procedure calling from C

Tags: c, assembly, intel, x86-16

I need to develop a procedure for Assembly language and call that procedure from C language (pass a string and return an integer value). My assembly procedure works fine "stand-alone". I need help with connecting them together.

Program is supposed to run on Intel 8086. I need to use MASM or emu8086 as assembler/simulator. Kindly recommend a C compiler and also a way to make the simple C program that is able to call the assembly procedure and get the returned value.

How can I pass a string to this external function?
How can I connect the ASM file and the C file? (How will the compiler know where is the definition/code for this procedure?)
How can I get the string sent from C in Assembly language, also how to return the integer to C?

Comment: Since you didn't upvote or even comment, I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> recommend a C compiler

Not enough info, however if your platform is significant enough, chances are that GCC already supports it.

> and also a way to make the simple C program that is able to call the assembly procedure and get the returned value.

The way for writing simple C programs is using a text editor. (Oh wait, you're interested in the code? Here it goes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo();

int main()
{
    int i = foo();
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Yes this is exactly what i need. Just a few clarifications/suggestions. Sorry for not providing sufficient information in the first place.

How can i pass a string to this external function?
How can i connect the ASM file and the C file? (How will the compiler know where is the definition/code for this procedure?)
How can i get the string sent from C in Assembly language, also how to return the integer to C?

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @user1969973 You read a C tutorial before asking? `foo("HelloWorld");`