# Assembly procedure calling from C (Intel 8086)

Tags: c, assembly, intel, x86-16

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intel 8086 Assembly procedure calling from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278373/intel-8086-assembly-procedure-calling-from-c)

I need to prepare a procedure in Assembly for Intel 8086 able to be called from a C (pass a string and return an integer value (16bit)). My assembly procedure works perfectly fine "stand-alone". I need help with connecting them together.

Program is supposed to run on Intel 8086. I need to use MASM or emu8086 as assembler/simulator. Kindly recommend a C compiler and also a way to make the simple C program that is able to call the assembly procedure and get the returned value.

*How can I connect the ASM file and the C file? (How will the compiler know where is the definition/code for this procedure?)*

*How can I receive the string sent from C in Assembly language, also how to return the integer to C from Assembly?*

Comment: Here's the [HOWTO for GCC](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html)

Comment: To get a 16-bit C compiler you'll have to break into a museum.  Try the Borland Museum, door is always open.

Comment: gcc is a fine compiler, but it's mostly for 32- (or 64-) bit code. It is possible to beat it into producing 16-bit code, but it's a PITA. I would suggest asking your instructor to recommend a suitable compiler.